# Jupyter notebook matplotlib figures missing in exported pdf

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

When generating a pdf in jupyter notebook, everything works great, but I would like to keep the inline figures inside the pdf, as well as the notebook.

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('png', 'pdf')

save_figures = True

x = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
if save_figures:
    plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

The figures appear inline, but in the pdf what is printed instead is:

```
<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>

<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

The same thing appears in the pdf if I export from the web or use `nbconvert` to export to pdf from the command line.

Are there any additional commands that I need to invoke in order to get this to work?

Comment: I came across the same issue. I want to use it for 3d plot to adjust the view angles etc, so `%matplotlib inline` is not an option for me. Is there going to be a fix for that issue?

Comment: Reported as a bug: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3295

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you change the `%matplotlib notebook` to `%matplotlib inline`, then PDF export with jupyter's nbconvert works fine for me. The `%matplotlib notebook` magic renders the plot in an interactive way that I suspect isn't properly recognized by LaTeX, which is used during the PDF conversion.

Alternatively, if you have to use `%matplotlib notebook` for some reason, the export to HTML with jupyter's nbconvert (`jupyter nbconvert --to='html' Test.ipynb`) seems to preserve the plot. I am then able to print this HTML file to a PDF from a web browser and the plot is present in the final PDF.

Comment: Perfect! Yep, interactive plots don't seem to be rendered but using `inline` works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to override `%matplotlib notebook` from the command line so static figures are being exported instead?

Comment: `%matplotlib inline` did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Crude solution to interactive problem:
in interactive function save figure to a file

```
fig.savefig("pieCharts.png")
```

in next cell display a file:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image("pieCharts.png")
```

In PDF only output of the 2nd line will be displayed with image as changed in interactive function.

Comment: This worked for me for PDF export, and also solved issues with the notebook file size and image caching.