# How to reload image in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In my notebook, I can display image in markdown from the same folder like this:

```
<img src="files/adaptive_filter.png" alt="Schema of adaptive filter" height="100">
```

If I use the code without the `files/` in `src` it does not work.

Now I changed the image and the ipython notebook is still showing the original one. I try to remove it from code and restart the notebook, it does not help.

What I should do? Are the images stored somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your browser is probably caching it - try refreshing the page.

Comment: It does not help. I have done hard refresh multiple times.

Comment: You may need to clear cached images in your browser manually as well. In Chrome (Version 85.0) for example by using "More tools > Clear browsing data".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, where I was using a class of my own to output some python plots and embed them in an IPython notebook.  A hack way to solve this would be to add a random argument to the end of your image url.  For example

```
<img src="files/adaptive_filter.png?1" alt="Schema of adaptive filter" height="100">
```

will not be cached in the same place as

```
<img src="files/adaptive_filter.png?2" alt="Schema of adaptive filter" height="100">
```

A programatic way to do this would be to include the picture via python, instead of markdown, for instance:

```
# pick a random integer with 1 in 2 billion chance of getting the same
# integer twice
import random
__counter__ = random.randint(0,2e9)

# now use IPython's rich display to display the html image with the
# new argument
from IPython.display import HTML, display
display(HTML('<img src="files/adaptive_filter.png?%d" ' +
             'alt="Schema of adaptive filter" ' +
             'height="100">' % __counter__))
```

Should update the image everytime you run the code cell

Answer (score 5):

I ran into exactly the same problem. The following procedure works for me:

In the folder where your .ipynb file resides, there is a cache directory called .ipynb_checkpoints/. There should be a file in that cache directory that has the same file name as the one you are working on. Now remove/delete that cache file in the .ipynb_checkpoint/ directory then reload the browser. You should be able to see the updated image.

My environment: macOS 10.14.2, Chrome browser 71.0, and Jupyter 1.0.0 installed through anaconda.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the Jupyter notebook VSCode extension, and I don't see any `.ipynb_checkpoints` directory. What works instead is the VSCode command `Python: Clear Cache and Reload Window`, but as stated it reloads the entire view. Beware of what data it might clear...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem of images caching in jupyter and not updating when the file is modified when using `matplotlib.pyplot`. I fixed it by using [IPython.display.Image](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image)

```py
from IPython.display import Image
def saveImage(path, show=True): 
    plt.savefig(path, facecolor="white", bbox_inches='tight') 
    if show: return Image(path)
```

Then **at the end of a code cell**, something like `saveImage('./someImage.png')` will save and display an image.

Similarly `Image('./someImage.png')` will display an image from disk (without saving).

This seems to avoid caching issues, and the image displays in PDF exports correctly (see also [Jupyter notebook matplotlib figures missing in exported pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305607/jupyter-notebook-matplotlib-figures-missing-in-exported-pdf) for the answer this is based on).

In my case, it helped reduce the size of the jupyter notebook, preventing it from crashing when rendering and updating `matplotlib.pyplot` charts.

Answer (score -1):

1. In ipynb file directory,use `ls` command ,it will display a hidden
   directory *.ipynb_checkpoints*
2. Delete the *.ipynb_checkpoints* directory ,then rerun the cell
   code,you will see the newest image.